# GitHub Actions: pylint fails with F0001: No module named __init__.py (fatal)

Tags: python-3.x, github, grep, github-actions, pylint

The following GitHub Pylint starter-workflow fails with lots of `pylint` F0001 errors.

This is the
[github-workflow](https://github.com/actions/starter-workflows/blob/9482241d4bee946d31163d5b268d6fb813ca6609/ci/pylint.yml) source code:

```yaml
name: Pylint

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up Python 3.9
      uses: actions/setup-python@v2
      with:
        python-version: 3.9
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install pylint
    - name: Analysing the code with pylint
      run: |
        pylint `ls -R|grep .py$|xargs`
```

These are the errors that the workflow outputs:

```
Run pylint $(ls -R | grep '.py$' | xargs)
************* Module __init__.py
__init__.py:1:0: F0001: No module named __init__.py (fatal)
__init__.py:1:0: F0001: No module named __init__.py (fatal)
************* Module pet.py
pet.py:1:0: F0001: No module named pet.py (fatal)
************* Module Authorization.py
Authorization.py:1:0: F0001: No module named Authorization.py (fatal)
************* Module Http.py
Http.py:1:0: F0001: No module named Http.py (fatal)
__init__.py:1:0: F0001: No module named __init__.py (fatal)
...
Error: Process completed with exit code 17.
```

Why can't `pylint` find these modules?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

##### Cause of the failure

The GitHub action workflow contains a bug over here:

```yaml
 | run  
    pylint `ls -R|grep .py$|xargs`
```

##### The solution

The solution is to replace:

```yaml
    pylint `ls -R|grep .py$|xargs`
```

By:

```yaml
    pylint $(find . -name "*.py" | xargs)
```

#### Explanation of the bug

`ls -R` returns the files in the current directory with the following format:

```
./dir1:
__init__.py file1.py

./dir1/dir2
__init__.py file2.py
```

If you filter the output of `ls -R` with `grep .py$`, you'll lose the path to the `*.py` files. `pylint` cannot find these files.

As a result, `pylint` fails with F0001 errors:

```sh
$ pylint --help-msg=F0001
:fatal (F0001):
  Used when an error occurred preventing the analysis of a module (unable to
  find it for instance). This message belongs to the master checker.
```

Comment: This issue is currently open at: <https://github.com/actions/starter-workflows/issues/636>

Answer (score 0):

Just write  in the terminal your file name,  not the path -- like this :
(my file is Omar.py)

```
$ pylint Omar.py
```